# How to count the number of sentences in a text in R?

Tags: r, text-mining

I read a text into R using the `readChar()` function. I aim at testing the hypothesis that the sentences of the text have as many occurrences of letter "a" as occurrences of letter "b". I recently discovered the `{stringr}` package, which helped me a great deal to do useful things with my text such as counting the number of characters and the total number of occurrences of each letter in the entire text. Now, I need to know the number of sentences in the whole text. Does R have any function, which can help me do that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you @gui11aume for your answer. A very good package I just found that can help do the work is `{openNLP}`. This is the code to do that:

```
install.packages("openNLP") ## Installs the required natural language processing (NLP) package
install.packages("openNLPmodels.en") ## Installs the model files for the English language
library(openNLP) ## Loads the package for use in the task
library(openNLPmodels.en) ## Loads the model files for the English language

text = "Dr. Brown and Mrs. Theresa will be away from a very long time!!! I can't wait to see them again." ## This sentence has unusual punctuation as suggested by @gui11aume

x = sentDetect(text, language = "en") ## sentDetect() is the function to use. It detects and seperates sentences in a text. The first argument is the string vector (or text) and the second argument is the language.
x ## Displays the different sentences in the string vector (or text).

[1] "Dr. Brown and Mrs. Theresa will be away from a very long time!!! "
[2] "I can't wait to see them again."

length(x) ## Displays the number of sentences in the string vector (or text).

[1] 2
```

The `{openNLP}` package is really great for natural language processing in R and you can find a good and short intro to it [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:8-Jur-gt8YAJ%3acran.r-project.org/web/packages/openNLP/vignettes/openNLP.pdf%20&hl=fr&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShvBkPPtxSrvvMx7HDpGyj_H7y70aUg8BshK5XqMZ6ZGqttMdwfJ9rbWBU-4XDx_1JnhezTbkkhQ8EguEsK1D5dm3f3v9SfJlEJAezW4zVbh6kHAMfFyKQ7zqvH_l4pYrR3ypQC&sig=AHIEtbTsZrcI1ahhYG1arZ6GNLTuXd5aKA) or you can check out the package's documentation [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3ac3QktuUpX3oJ%3acran.r-project.org/web/packages/openNLP/openNLP.pdf%20&hl=fr&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShYHnZ2a0hvH_Gli-5OO7V_3-xAmPe2IEM_sSrZheAIACd-123jau2Eql4KW5Fuc6jyuPxq64KSnofr9ara8bnzRkGj6O-Upu2nzlcktuTtI6N4tnnQ09ZHrQf2GUThICf9P4Af&sig=AHIEtbSSjE27yDgWRsrm-cLTndWLgKH6dA).

Three more languages are supported in the package. You just need to install and load the corresponding model files.

1. `{openNLPmodels.es}` for Spanish
2. `{openNLPmodels.ge}` for German
3. `{openNLPmodels.th}` for Thai

Comment: @ManojKumar Actually, the `openNLP` package was drastically changed a few years ago. Check the second answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370518/r-opennlp-could-not-find-function-sentdetect

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is sentence tokenization, and it is not as straightforward as it seems, even in English (sentences like "I met Dr. Bennett, the ex husband of Mrs. Johson." can contain full stops).

R is definitely *not* the best choice for natural language processing. If you are [Python](http://www.python.org) proficient, I suggest you have a look at the [nltk](http://nltk.org/) module, which covers this and many other topics. You can also copy the code from [this blog post](http://blog.thegrandlocus.com/2012/06/The-elements-of-style), which does sentence tokenization and word tokenization.

If you want to stick to R, I would suggest you count the end-of-sentence characters (`.`, `?`, `!`), since you are able to count characters. A way of doing it with a regular expression is like so:

```
text <- 'Hello world!! Here are two sentences for you...'
length(gregexpr('[[:alnum:] ][.!?]', text)[[1]])
```

Comment: Why is R not a good choice, @SavedByJESUS seems to have found a package that contains a function to split the text into sentences. In addition, your solution in R is not really a solution for reasons you give yourself, e.g. Dr. Fastolfe.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra R is a such a fast-growing programming language with all the additional packages being added daily that it's just hard to keep up with everything :)