# Text mining in R: delete first sentence of each document

Tags: r, text-mining

I have several documents and do not need the first sentence of each document.
I could not find a solution so far.

Here is an example. The structure of the data looks like this

| case_number | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Today is a good day. It is sunny. |
| 2 | Today is a bad day. It is rainy. |

So the results should look like this

| case_number | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | It is sunny. |
| 2 | It is rainy. |

Here is the example dataset:

```r
case_number <- c(1, 2)

text <- c("Today is a good day. It is sunny.",
          "Today is a bad day. It is rainy.")

data <- data.frame(case_number, text)
```

Comment: I suggest looking at some NLP related libraries in R. They ususally have preimplemented sentence splitting functionalities. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712878/r-break-corpus-into-sentences

Comment: If your sentence always ends with known punctuation marks, it is essentially "remove everything before the puncutations", similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767164/use-gsub-remove-all-string-before-first-white-space-in-r (i.e. to replace the white space in the question with your known punctuation marks)

Comment: Thank's benson23. Your right. I can solve it by excluding everything before first punctuation. I was thinking a little bit more complex. That's a very easy way to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a chance that sentences might include some punctuation (e.g. abbreviations or numerics), and you are using some text mining library anyway, it makes perfect sense to let it handle tokenization.

With `{tidytext}` :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

# exmple with punctuation in 1st sentence
data <- data.frame(case_number = c(1, 2),
                   text = c("Today is a good day, above avg. for sure, by 5.1 points. It is sunny.",
                            "Today is a bad day. It is rainy."))
# tokenize to sentences, converting tokens to lowercase is optional
data %>% 
  unnest_sentences(s, text)
#>   case_number                                                        s
#> 1           1 today is a good day, above avg. for sure, by 5.1 points.
#> 2           1                                             it is sunny.
#> 3           2                                      today is a bad day.
#> 4           2                                             it is rainy.

# drop 1st record of every case_number group
data %>% 
  unnest_sentences(s, text) %>% 
  filter(row_number() > 1, .by = case_number)
#>   case_number            s
#> 1           1 it is sunny.
#> 2           2 it is rainy.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>